# How to connect atmega32u4 to USB

Tags: usb, atmega

I want to use a USB connection with the ATmega32u4, but there are 6 pins in the datasheet (http://www.atmel.com/Images/doc7766.pdf) associated with the USB. I don't know which ones connect to the generic USB connections. Can someone show me how they are setup?

Comment: Link above to the spec is not valid (apr 2016). What is best point to start read about own software with USB protocol? Precise: raw chip, not arduino.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Section 21, "USB controller", subsection 21.3, "Typical Application Implementation", of the datasheet shows methods of connecting the device along with associated components to USB in various bus- or self-powered configurations.

Comment: Thank you! But can you tell me why the USB has five connections? What is the fifth one at the bottom of the diagram do?

Comment: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/35462/why-does-micro-usb-2-0-have-5-pins-when-the-a-type-only-has-4

Comment: NO in the diagram. On the Datasheet listed

Comment: If you are not talking about the OTG ID pin (which you can leave unconnected), then give the name of the signal you are asking about.

Answer (score 0):

To connect this ATmega on USB, you should connect: 
Pin 3 (D-) with a 22 Ohm resistor in serial connected at pin 2(D-) of USB
Pin 4 (D+) with a 22 Ohm resistor in serial connected at pin 3 (D+) of USB 
pin 35 (GND) connected at pin 1 of (GND)USB
pin 34 (VCC) connected at pin 4 of (VCC)USB

[image]