# Which ground plane connection will perform better in terms of EMC?

Tags: usb, grounding, emc, emi-filtering, ferrite-bead

In figure 12 of [these](https://www.ti.com/sc/docs/apps/msp/intrface/usb/emitest.pdf) EMI Design Guidelines
for USB Components, I can see that VBUS and Gnd signals from
the USB receptacle are **bypassed with ferrite beads and then connected to their respective power and ground planes**, while the **USB receptable itself is tied to the ground plane** at its connection points.
Following this guide, my design should look like the one below:

[image: ground wire from USB cable connected to the ground plane through a FB while USB shield connects straight to the ground plane]

However, after reverse engineering the PCB layout of a simple wired Razer mouse, I saw that they implemented the filtering of the ground signal slightly differently. Specifically, the ground signal from the USB cable **is tied to the ground plane** (no f.bead) while the USB shield* **connects to the ground plane through a ferrite bead.**

*Noted that in this case the USB cable is not connected to the PCB via a standard micro-B USB receptable like in the first case, but instead through a permanently attatched vertical 2mm pitch 5-pin header. So when I say shield for this second case I mean the 4th pin of the Razer USB cable which is the extension of a  bundle of thin copper wires (acting as a shield) that are wrapped around the other 4 wire signals (V, D-, D+, GND). In the first case, where a USB receptable is used, the 4th pin is the ID pin meant for [something else](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/35462/why-does-micro-usb-2-0-have-5-pins-when-the-a-type-only-has-4/140817#140817) , unrelated to this question.

My question: Are those two methods of connecting the gnd signal to the respective ground plane similar in terms of EMC performance, or should I expect to see my board fail at the test house after following one design over the other? I would be inclined to follow the design guide had I not seen an actual product designed in a different way.

[image: ground wire from USB cable connected straight to the ground plane while USB shield connects to the ground plane through a FB]

Comment: There is always a bit of mystery to emissions. Sometimes you have to build it and try it before you can be sure. I would probably follow the TI design guide. Make sure you are following the right section (I don't know if you are making a host or a USB device).

Comment: Usually I put a common mode choke on the data lines. This is for USB 2.0. I don't have experience with any higher version. I assume there are USB 3.0 compatible common mode chokes also.

Comment: This question also has an answer here, https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/269313/117785

Comment: @Ale..chenski yes it does :)