# Why do some USB Type B cables have an ID pinout but others have a DGND pinout, how do I tell the difference between them without ripping it apart?

Tags: usb, connector, pinout

[On this page](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/35462/why-does-micro-usb-2-0-have-5-pins-when-the-a-type-only-has-4), it is clear that the pinout for a Micro USB type B is:

VDD (+5V)
D- (Data-)
D+ (Data+)
ID (ID)
GND (Ground)

However, when I opened and stripped apart my Micro USB type B, it looks like this, where I have a DGND. Before I ruin another USB cable, how do I know which one has the ID pin instead of the DGND pin?  [image]

EDIT: The image was gathered from this link, the 'measurements' may be different but visually the pin layout looks the same (i.e. on the underside of the connector it has 1 pinout rather than 2): https://www.aliexpress.com/item/33060931097.html

Edit 2: I found the connecter on a video, here is the timestamp: https://youtu.be/9h78fjnWuA0?t=24

Comment: The USB standard does not provide -5 V, so something is wrong with your measurements

Comment: Depends on the cable. If it's Type A to Micro B the ID pin will be left floating to put the B end in slave mode, so there's no point in making it connectable. And what you've labelled DGND is the shield connection.

Comment: @Finbarr But I don't even have the pinout for it., i.e. it's not floating - it just doesn't seem to exist. Are there 2 types of type B connectors?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Firstly, that's a really unhelpfully labelled image. Really it should be:

- `+5V` - 5V supply rail (labelled `5V+` on your diagram)
- `D-`/`D+` - Data lines (correctly labelled on your diagram)
- `GND` - Ground for data and power (unhelpfully labelled `5V-` on your diagram)
- `Shield` - The connector metal shielding (wrongly labelled `DGND`)

These are the five wires that run in any standard USB2.0 cable. I say wires, the shield is usually a braided shell encasing the other four wires. Sometimes the shield is omitted in poor quality cables.

The `ID` is a function of the socket and not the cable. On ports which are capable of dual role host and device (such as mobile phones), also known as [On-The-Go (OTG)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB_On-The-Go) ports, this pin selects whether the port is host (shorted to `GND` internally by the plug) or a device (floating).

Because the `ID` is not connected to a wire, it is not surprising that it isn't broken out to a pad for attaching a wire too. Instead it will internally within the plug be directly shorted to the adjacent GND pin, or simply left unconnected to anything (a.k.a **floating**).

Comment: "horribly incorrectly labelled 5V- on your diagram" - well, uncommon but not horribly wrong. "-5V" would be wrong as there is no negative voltage. I read "5V-" as "5V rail, negative wire". Might make more sense if there are several rails floating with respect to each other.

Comment: @asdfex It's horrible labelling. 0V or GND make it clear that all the other pins are referenced to this one. 5V+ and 5V- imply that the D+/D- pins are completely isolated from these two, which is not the case.

Comment: I see, so just to confirm, I need to dig out a USB OTG connector that uses a USB Type B connector. Or simply a USB Type B OTG connector. Would it be clear which cables support USB OTG and which don't without opening it up?

Comment: @Annon see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB_hardware#USB_On-The-Go_connectors and the two Mini and two Micro plugs. Both of them have A and B types. The AB types are designed to indicate which one is host-side (A) and which one is device-side (B). There are also matching host/device sockets. The fun part is that you can put a B-type cable plug into both A and B sockets (so a host-capable device can work both as Host and as Device), but you can't put a A-type cable plug into B-type socket (so a dumb device-only device can't accept a host-side on the cable, such cables are 'directional!).

Comment: @Annon But interestingly, it's only true for Mini and Micro. Because they are newer inventions. The oldest "classic" type-A and type-B (the 'computer one' and the 'printer one' :) ) are not designed to work that way, type-A plug won't fit into type-B socket. They simply didn't consider back then that it's handy to allow for such reuse.. Anyways, totally in theory in a perfect world, you'd just look at the socket and at the cables and bang you know it.

Comment: @Annon But the reality, cheap cables won't follow anything. I'm sure you can even buy B-B cables that should have NO sense (bus needs a host!). Half of my USB cables are "data-only", because the manufacturer cut the cost and included only 2 lines instead of 5 (who needs d+/d-/shield to charge a night lamp, right?). I am 100% you can easily find nice-looking cables that should be OTG-capable with proper A/B ends, that won't follow the standard. I'd say, if you need it badly, instead of destroying the cables open, just grab two HOST side sockets and make a trivial tester.

Comment: @Annon Micro/Mini host-side sockets will accept both types of the plugs, so you can insert any cable. And since they are host-side sockets, they will have all 6 lines (V+,D+,D-,GN,SH,ID) broken out, because the host-side-capable device, once cable is inserted, it has to know which role it should assume. So take two Mini/Micro-A sockets, plug both sides of the cable in them, and just check if all pairs are pass through properly, and if IDs are as expected, and it should show if the cable is good or not.